# Civilization IV turns into a black screen after revealing map

Tags: linux-mint, steam, games

I'm running Linux Mint 19 on a laptop Gateway NV51M and I have installed Civilization iv on Steam using Proton.

The game runs out of box.

But after I (or the PC) build Stonehenge wonder (Important: this wonder centers the map). The screen turns into a black screen.

The game does not crash, I can hear the music, and use the shortcuts for units. But I don't see anything.

I can't access to the world map, and if I press F10, I access to the city control but everything is black as well.

Comment: sounds like a window manager problem. This event plays a full-screen video, so perhaps there is some buffer, driver or library missing.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04.2.
Updating `wine` with these components help me to fix it:

```
winetricks d3dx9 corefonts msxml3 msxml4
```

Probably, only `msxml4` might be needed.

Comment: So I had the exact same issue (though on Ubuntu 18.04.4), tried this fix and now the map is black from the start of the game.

Comment: I installed d3dx9, msxml3, msxml4 using protontricks gui and that helped with this issue. Was happening for me after researching Calendar.

Comment: This solution worked for me on a 2019 MacBook Pro (Intel Graphics) with macOS 10.15+ using the porting kit (a wrapper for wineskin focused on mac game configs). You can add the above components in the game's wineskin app (advanced tools) > tools > winetricks > search & tick the components you need > Run & Close.